# C#, Nuget add framework assembiles in "nuget pack someproj.csproj"

Tags: c#, nuget

I'm using `nuget pack myproj.csproj` without .nuspec file.

But this command doesn't include my project's framework assemblies like '`WindowBase`', '`UIAutomationProvider`' or something.

Comment: Framework assemblies aren't redistributable. Why are you expecting them to be included in your package?

Comment: @codran It is not redistribute of framework assemblies. Auto include to my project after install my nupkg. chek this [Nuspec reference](http://docs.nuget.org/Create/Nuspec-Reference) we can add framework assemblies in .nuspec file as NOT redistribute. just auto include  after install it... but it seems.. there is no option to add this properties on `nuget pack myproj.csproj` I'm finding on this solution

Answer (score 0):

There is no options to add framework assemblies when nuget packaging without .nuspec file.

must be sure .nuspec file on folder contains .csproj or something.